# multiple y over x in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am new in using ggplot 2.
When I used `plot()` I just used `points()` or `lines()` to add another y over the same x, how solve this in ggplot?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=xVal, y=y1Val ,colour="darkred")) + geom_line(size=2)
```

before I got my solution with:

```
plot(df$xVal, df$y1Val,color="darkred")
pints(df$xVal, df$y2Val,color="blue")
```

I do have 3 variables and want to plot 2 of them over the the last one. I think the normal plot() example points out what I want:
e.g.

```
x y1 y2
1 2 3
5 4 6
3 3 5
2 2 4
```

Now plot two lines with y1 and y2 over the x.

How to deal with the color that I can set the legend with the correct names?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide a small minimal working example?  Basically make a data frame called df with xVal, y1Val and y2Val.  I'm also having a little bit of a difficult time determining what your question is.  You have one kind of about plotting and one about legends.  What is your explicit question?

Comment: +1 `pints` is an awesome typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmmm, I'm not entirely clear what you want, so I'll offer a suggestion and you can recommend corrections to match what your desired output.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(16)
df <- data.frame(x = sample(1:10), y1 = sample(1:10), y2 = sample(1:10))
df[5,2] <- NA
df[7,3] <- NA
df <- df[complete.cases(df), ]
df2 <- melt(df, id = "x")
df2
# > df2
#   x variable value
# 1 1       y1     2
# 2 5       y1     4
# 3 3       y1     3
# 4 2       y1     2
# 5 1       y2     3
# 6 5       y2     6
# 7 3       y2     5
# 8 2       y2     4
ggplot(df2, aes(x = x, y = value, color = variable)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) + geom_point(size = 3) + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image: lines and plots]

Comment: Thanks you are getting the y1 and y2 from the same column called yval - but I do have 2 columns in df for y - each for one line.

Comment: It is quite funny if I take your example I am getting: 'x       ,variable,value' - weather I take my stuff I get: 'Var1,Var2,value' from melt and plot is not working...

Comment: Thanks Ryan I will use the old 'plot()'. The ggplot is much worse. I do have xts objects with around 500000 values each - with plot() and coredata() automatically only the pairs are used - right now I first have to use 'na.omit' and afterwards having lots of missvalues.. don't know where they come from. I wanted to use ggplot because of the grid, but thats not worth it.

Comment: Thank you - works but: I need data handling...  - df2 <- df1[complete.cases(df1), ] - df3 <- coredata(df2) -
df4 <-as.data.frame(df3) -
df5 <- melt(df4, id = "x") - in addition to plot with plot().